# Linking css file from assets folder into webpack html template file

Tags: css, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have a template html file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>aquaWeb</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="???">        
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="some-placeholder">
            I want to stylize this placeholder
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to stylize the placeholder with rules defined in `/assets/css/placeholder.css`. How I can attach that css file into this template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`html-webpack-include-assets-plugin`](https://github.com/jharris4/html-webpack-include-assets-plugin) in order to add external assets to the html.

```
var HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin = require('html-webpack-include-assets-plugin');

/// ...

plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
  new HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin({ 
     assets: [
        'path/to/your/css/placeholder.css'
     ], 
     append: true })
]
```